# Expand table columns proportionally to textwidth

Tags: tables, width, fullwidth

I have a simple table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
First entry & 2nd    & 3rd little longer & Forth & Fifth\\ \hline\hline
4.7\%  & 11.7\% & 2.5\%         & 80.5\%         & 0.7\%  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I want it to use the whole page width by proportionally increasing the width of each column. So I do not want column widths to be spread equally; like this because the long line breaks:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {|*{5}{X[l]|}}
\hline
First entry & 2nd    & 3rd little longer & Forth & Fifth\\ \hline\hline
4.7\%  & 11.7\% & 2.5\%         & 80.5\%         & 0.7\%  \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\caption{tabu}
\end{table}
```

Already tried tabulary but it only reduces the size of a table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
First entry & 2nd    & 3rd little longer & Forth & Fifth\\ \hline\hline
4.7\%  & 11.7\% & 2.5\%         & 80.5\%         & 0.7\%  \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
\caption{tabulary}
\end{table}
```

Here the output of a three samples (including a dummy text to see the page width):

[image]

Comment: Check out the tabularx package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{2}{X|}l|*{2}{X|}}
\hline
First entry & 2nd    & 3rd little longer & Forth & Fifth\\ \hline\hline
4.7\%  & 11.7\% & 2.5\%         & 80.5\%         & 0.7\%  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{tabularx}
\noindent X\hrulefill X % just for showing text width
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The longest column (3) is typeset with an `l` column. The remaining columns are evenly distributed among the remaining width by using `X` columns.

[image]

Comment: what does `*{2}{X|}` mean?

Comment: @Tiina it's just shorthand for "two copies of `X|`", that is `X|X|`. (In this case it doesn't actually save any space, but for many repeated columns it can make things much more compact.)

Answer (score 3):

## No-Package Method

You need to know the following things:

- macro containing the width from left margin to right margin: `\textwidth`
- macro containing value of cell separator width: `\tabcolsep`
- how many cells: *determined by you*

Then you just need to do the math. This can be accomplished with `\dimexpr`:

### Calculate Cell Width Based on Text Area Width `\textwidth`

*cell width as percentage of text area width* - 2(*separator width*)

```
\dimexpr .40\textwidth-2\tabcolsep
```

## Example

Let's say that we have three columns. I will choose the paragraph column type `p` for line wrapping, which naturally makes you to set a maximum width.

- 2 columns of 20% of text width = 40% of text width
- 1 column of 60% of text width = 60% of text width

As long as the total of all column calculations = 100%, you're good to go!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% Used for visual illustration of tabular width
\begin{document}
Do not forget to remove the {\the\parindent} auto-indentation when testing widths. 

\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{2mm}% proof that this table is maxed out
\bigbreak
\noindent% <== removes auto-indentation of article class for new paragraphs that do not follow a heading
\begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr.20\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr.20\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr.60\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\toprule
Dimension & Value+Unit & Description \\
\midrule
\textbackslash tabcolsep & \the\tabcolsep & The amount of space for each vertical cell border. \\
\textbackslash textwidth & \the\textwidth & The width from left margin to right margin. \\
\textbackslash parindtent & \the\parindent & The auto-indentation width. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## Notes

`tabularx` defines column type `X` to do essentially the same thing, except that it will automatically try to find the values for column type `p{}`.

http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf
[image]